# How do I fix the 'experimental syntax' error when starting a new React Native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, eslint, eslintrc

I start a new React Native project following this rule in link but this error showed:

[image]

> ESLint: Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one
> of the following parser plugin(s)

Here is how I have modified the .eslintrc.js:

```
 module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser',
    requireConfigFile: false,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
};
```

How can I resolve this experimental syntax error?

Comment: Can you please include the full error message (including what plugins it says need to be enabled)? The error message in the screenshot is cut off on the right.